# Цитата внутри авторской речи - как оформлять?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

> Ведь "Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык —
> молодец", — учит Суворов.

Как правильно оформить такое предложение?

1. Не уверен насчёт того, что оно должно выглядеть как прямая речь, то есть с запятой + тире после цитаты, потому что есть на Грамоте и в материалах к ЕГЭ такое: "После закрывающих кавычек ставится только тире (независимо от того, каким знаком препинания заканчивается прямая речь) в тех случаях, когда в последующих авторских словах содержится характеристика прямой речи, ее оценка и т. д. (авторская ремарка начинается словами *так говорит, так указывает, вот что сказал, вот как описывает* и т. п.): «Ничего не случилось» — так говорил ум; «Случилось» — так говорило сердце; «Нет ничего прекраснее этих снежных вершин» — так описывает эту местность один путешественник; «Будь внимателен и осторожен!» — вот что он сказал мне на прощание". Возможно, здесь как раз такой случай?
2. Не уверен также, что цитата должна начинаться с заглавной буквы.

Прошу помощи!

Answer (score 2):

*Ведь "Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык — молодец", — учит Суворов.*

Не-не, такое оформление не является верным.
Ведь слово "ведь" Суворову не принадлежит, поэтому в самом конце **нельзя** писать *учит Суворов*.

Есть несколько вариантов записи слов генералиссимуса.

1. Береги пулю на три дни, а иногда и на целую кампанию, когда негде взять! Стреляй редко, да метко. Штыком коли крепко, пуля обмишулится, а штык не обмишулится. Пуля дура, штык молодец ([ссылка 1](http://militera.lib.ru/science/suvorov/02.html)).
2. Береги пулю на три дня, и иногда и на целую кампанию, как негде взять. Стреляй редко, да метко; штыком коли крепко. Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык — молодец ([ссылка 2](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/2307/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F)).
3. Береги пулю на три дня, а иногда и на целую кампанию, когда негде взять. Стреляй редко, да метко, штыком коли крепко. Пуля обмишулится, а штык не обмишулится. Пуля — дура, а штык — молодец! ([ссылка 3](https://ls.pushkininstitute.ru/lsslovar/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%90._%D0%92._%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2._%C2%AB%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%C2%BB)).

Цитирование — в зависимости от варианта:

"...Пуля обмишулится, а штык не обмишулится. Пуля дура, штык молодец", — говорил Суворов;
"Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык — молодец", — учил Суворов;
"Пуля обмишулится, а штык не обмишулится. Пуля — дура, а штык — молодец!" — наставлял Суворов.

Comment: Ответ является комментарием. Спасибо, ув. Римма, я знаком с основными правилами цитирования. Меня интересует оформление именно цитаты внутри авторских слов.
Аргумент, что раз слово "ведь" не часть цитаты, то мы не можем писать после неё "учит Суворов" - на мой взгляд, слаб, поскольку очевидно, что "учит Суворов" относится лишь к тому, что в кавычках. К примеру, когда мы видим цитату, оформленную как часть придаточного, то прекрасно понимаем, чтО - цитата, а чтО - слова автора.

Comment: У Вас в предложении, извините, нет никакой "именно цитаты внутри авторских слов" и никакого придаточного. Очевидно, что Вы пытаетесь оформить цитату как прямую речь. (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=163#pp163) Но в этом случае слово "ведь" не является частью цитаты.

Comment: Я как раз и сомневаюсь, что тут уместно оформление прямой речью. Возможно, там тире не требуется, а цитату стоит рассматривать как часть предложения? Ведь "пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык — молодец", учит Суворов.

Comment: @Сius Не хватает детали, которая ставила бы крест на прямой речи, а именно союза КАК. Перед ним тире не бывает.

Comment: @shampar да, думал над этим, но тогда предложение приобретает оттенок журналистики, потому что слова, вводящие в цитату (наподобие "как говорит", "как утверждает" и проч.) обычно там используются.

Comment: @shampar а может, следует поставить после "ведь" двоеточие?? Смотрите, мы вполне можем написать: _Ведь Суворов говорил: "Цитата"_. И, думаю, вполне можем перенести цитату в середину авторских слов: _Ведь: "Цитата", — говорил Суворов_. Как полагаете? Это не совсем обычный случай получается, но вроде как всё логично и по правилам.

Comment: Союз не может «открывать» прямую речь (а это будет выглядеть ПР, чего избегаете — и двоеточие, и тире). Уберёте прописную, тире и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @shampar cоюз может открывать прямую речь, смотрим в Нацкорпусе: _Встретит какую гладкую и: «Приходи, Марья, я с тебя допрос сниму»_; _И: «Хозяин BMW еще долго не будет знать, как подступиться к этой идущей без его участия жизни, как сковырнуть этот мирок, как заставить его работать на себя и на свой BMW»_.

Comment: Пропущенный глагол (начинает, клянчит, скулит, предлагает и т. д.) не может замещаться союзом. Или не видите пропажу? В качестве вводящих слов употребляются и существительные. Как и глаголы, они имеют значение высказывания или мысли. Их здесь также нет. Второй же пример без контекста нет смысла комментировать. На прямую речь накак не тянет. //// Если вернутся к вопросу... Авторские слова при прямой речи случайным образом не рубятся на до и после неё.

Comment: Если вы хотите что-то обсудить, не используйте комментарии, а лучше используйте [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/).

Answer (score 1):

• Дополнительные сведения ([Как оформлять цитаты?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76))

> **Между словами цитирующего и следующей за ними цитатой:**
>
> а) ставят двоеточие, если предшествующие цитате слова цитирующего предупреждают о том, что далее следует цитата:
> *Пастернак писал: «Существует психология творчества, проблемы поэтики. Между тем изо всего искусства именно его происхожденье переживается всего непосредственнее, и о нем не приходится строить догадок».*
>
> б) ставят точку, если внутри цитаты или за нею находятся слова цитирующего, вводящие цитату в текст фразы:
> *Хорошо сказал об этом Пастернак. «Существует психология творчества, проблемы поэтики. Между тем изо всего искусства именно его происхожденье переживается всего непосредственнее, и о нем не приходится строить догадок», — писал он в «Охранной грамоте».*
>
> в) не ставят никаких знаков, если цитата выступает как дополнение или как часть придаточного предложения:
> *Пастернак писал, что «изо всего искусства именно его происхожденье переживается всего непосредственнее».*

• Дополнительные примеры (в зависимости от варианта)

"...Пуля обмишулится, а штык не обмишулится" — эти слова ведь стали афоризмом.

Сегодня, когда стратегия и тактика ведения войны претерпели глобальные изменения, слова Суворова "пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится..." имеют другое значение.

Полководец умел разговаривать "с солдатами их языком", ведь именно он учил, что "пуля обмишулится, а штык не обмишулится".

Comment: Я ведь, кажется, ясно написал, что знаком с основными правилами цитирования. Меня не интересуют варианты с перетасовками слов, меня интересует пунктуационное оформление именно моего варианта.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ, полученный от ИРЯ РАН.**

**Моё письмо:**

> Здравствуйте! Прошу Вашей помощи, не могу решить для себя пару
> пункуационных задачек. Обращался на разные форумы, но увы...
>
> Первая задачка такова: как правильно оформлять цитату, которая внутри
> авторских слов? *Ведь "Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля —
> дура, штык — молодец", — учит Суворов.* В таком варианте она выглядит
> как прямая речь, но я не нашёл ни у Розенталя, ни у Лопатина правил о
> допустимости или недопустимости вот такого «висячего» слова перед
> прямой речью, как у меня союз «ведь». Да и примеров в Нацкорпусе не
> нашёл. Я полагаю необычным, но допустимым вариант с двоеточием: *Ведь:
> "Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык — молодец",
> — учит Суворов*. Но выглядит тоже сомнительно. Где-то мне ответили, что
> можно оформить цитату без пунктуационных атрибутов прямой речи,
> приблизив её к правилу про цитату, не являющуюся самостоятельным
> предложением:  *Ведь "пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля —
> дура, штык — молодец", учит Суворов*. Но опять-таки «приблизив к
> правилу» — не то, что мне надо. Вариантов много, и все логичны, однако
> мне хочется знать, как всё же правильно с точки зрения норм
> пунктуации.
>
> К этому вопросу примыкает ещё один: как оформлять разрыв цитаты
> авторским словом, которое не является глаголом речи/мысли? У Лопатина
> в § 135 рассматриваются только случаи с такими глаголами, а у
> Розенталя из похожих имеется лишь указание на случай ««Пиковая...» ли
> это «Дама»?». А если мне надо воткнуть между двумя фрагментами цитаты
> тот же союз «ведь»? *«Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится...», ведь
> «...пуля — дура, штык — молодец», — учит Суворов.* Так ли будет
> правильно?

**Ответ:**

> Добрый день!
> Способы пунктуационного оформления предложений, приведенных Вами, не
> регламентированы нормативными справочниками по пунктуации (во всяком
> случае, четкой рекомендации относительно подобных предложений в
> известных нам справочниках, таких как «Правила русской орфографии и
> пунктуации» 1956 г., полный академический справочник «Правила русской
> орфографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина, нет).
> Представленные Вами в первой части запроса варианты предложений
> некорректны с грамматической точки зрения, цитата не просто разрывает
> авторское предложение, она нарушает логико-синтаксические связи в нем.
> Каноническим и единственно допустимым с нормативной точки зрения
> является предложение, построенное следующим образом: *Ведь Суворов
> учит: «Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык —
> молодец».*   Предложения, подобные тем, что были приведены Вами,
> свойственны скорее непринужденной разговорной речи; как известно,
> пунктуационное оформление разговорных конструкций практически не
> регламентировано нормативными справочниками, в этом случае возможно
> находить соотношение между конструкциями разговорной и письменной
> речи. Так, мы не рекомендуем ставить двоеточие после союза *ведь*: в
> авторитетном «Справочнике издателя и автора» А. Э. Мильчина, Л. К.
> Чельцовой (2009) указано, что двоеточие ставится после слов
> цитирующего перед цитатой, если слова цитирующего (авторские слова)
> вводят цитату, предупреждают читателя о ней [см. параграф 8.7.1]; союз
> *ведь* не вводит цитату. Поскольку союз *ведь*, как и прочие союзы, не
> входит в грамматическую основу предложения, думается, в Вашем случае
> можно оформить предложение — в соответствии с правилом, согласно
> которому после прямой речи (или цитаты) ставится запятая и тире, а
> слова автора начинаются со строчной буквы, если прямая речь (или
> цитата) стоит перед вводящими ее словами автора [см. полный
> академический справочник «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под
> ред. В. В. Лопатина (2006), § 134] — следующим образом: *Ведь «Пуля
> обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык — молодец», — учит
> Суворов.* С другой стороны, можно оформить предложение способом,
> предусмотренным правилом из полного академического справочника:
> «Цитата, включенная в авторское предложение на правах его компонента,
> выделяется кавычками (но начинается со строчной буквы), знаки
> препинания употребляются только те, которые диктуются самим авторским
> предложением» [см. § 143]. В соответствии с этим правилом предложение
> будет оформлено следующим образом: *Ведь «Пуля обмишулится, штык не
> обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык — молодец» учит Суворов.*
>
> Второе приведенное Вами предложение — *«Пуля обмишулится, штык не
> обмишулится...», ведь «...пуля — дура, штык — молодец», — учит Суворов*
> — также является трудным и не регламентированным справочниками
> пунктуационным случаем. Ваш вариант представляет собой комбинацию двух
> правил: с одной стороны, после цитаты, заключенной в кавычки и
> расположенной перед словами автора, ставится запятая и тире, с другой
> стороны, оба цитируемых фрагмента заключены в кавычки, вероятно, в
> соответствии с правилом выделения цитат и «чужих» слов [см. полный
> академический справочник «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под
> ред. В. В. Лопатина (2006), § 148, 149]. Однако многоточия в цитатах,
> как кажется, можно опустить с учетом правила цитирования отдельных
> слов и словосочетаний, содержащегося в «Справочнике издателя и автора»
> А. Э. Мильчина, Л. К. Чельцовой (2009), согласно которому «при таком
> цитировании многоточие допустимо не ставить, ибо читателю и без того
> ясно, что перед цитируемыми словами и после них опущены слова» [см.
> параграф 8.1.9]. Также, как кажется, можно применить указанное выше
> правило из § 143 полного академического справочника, чтобы избежать
> употребления запятой и тире перед авторскими словами. Таким образом,
> рассматриваемое предложение могло бы быть оформлено следующим образом:
> *«Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится», ведь «пуля — дура, штык —
> молодец» учит Суворов.*
>
> В заключение подчеркнем, что указанные выше
> способы оформления предложений с цитатами не могут квалифицироваться
> как нормативные, поскольку обсуждаемые пунктуационные случаи в
> настоящее время не регламентированы справочниками по пунктуации.
>
> С уважением
> Евгений Базаров, сотрудник отдела культуры русской речи
> ИРЯ РАН

Comment: Что-то как-то противоречиво пишет Базаров. Сначала говорит о некорректности, а потом предлагает точно такой же вариант. А где цитата включена в авторское предложение, пишет ее с прописной, до этого приводя правило о строчной...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец некорректно, я так понимаю, с точки зрения строгих правил. Он же делает оговорку о разговорной речи. Насчёт второго - сам не знаю, почему так. Мне этот вариант вообще непонятен. Тем не менее я сделал вывод, что *Ведь «Пуля обмишулится, штык не обмишулится: пуля — дура, штык — молодец», — учит Суворов* - допустимый вариант. Ответ  скинул просто для сведения, вдруг кому-то захочется его обсудить. Мне - точно не захочется:)